# Solr Frange Issues

Tags: solr

I have the following query in which I am using !frange function twice and the 
query is not returning any results. However if i use a single !frange function 
then the results come for the same query.

Is it now possible to execute two franges in a single query?

```
q="woolmark"&fq={!frange l=33787806 u=33787918}id&fq={!frange 
l=40817415}id&fq=createdOnGMTDate:[2011-07-01T14%3A30%3A00Z+TO+2011-07-21T14%3A30%3A00Z]
```

Regards,
Rohit

Answer (score 0):

The query parameters always should give 0 results.On id field you are asking for l=33787806 and u=33787918 and l=40817415 , obviously there cannot be such id

Comment: What I am trying to look for is id between two ranges basically. An id can be present between (u=33787918 and l=40817415)  or (l=40817415 and u=*).